# APEX Data Load Number Format

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I am relatively new to APEX and at the moment i am trying a few things to become better with it.

Now i have some problems with the **Data Upload Wizzard** from APEX. I created a table which has a NUMBER column in it. Now i try to upload some data to it via the data upload wizzard.

My Problem ist that if i upload a number with a comma (,) as the decimal seperator, like "*12000,00*", the "ORA-01722: invalid number" error pops up.

I tried to alter the "Globalization" settings in the  "File Details"-Tab to:
Group Separator = .
Decimal Character = ,

However if i upload a file with different formats like,

**12000.00;

12000,00;

12,000.12;

12.000,13;**

only the number 12000.00 is getting inserted.

It seems like APEX totaly ignores the globalization settings. Is there a way i can upload numbers with a comma (,) as decimal seperator. Do i have to set a specific format in the format column? So far i tried "999990,99" and "999G990D99" as format masks but non of them seem to work.

Thanks for your input in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Set the parameter `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` along with the `FORMAT`:

```
'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = .,'
```